# In file object, method "readline()" seems not working in my code

Tags: python, file, methods, python-3.6

```
def load_words():
    '''
    file_name (string): the name of the file containing 
    the list of words to load    

    Returns: a list of valid words. Words are strings of lowercase letters.

    Depending on the size of the word list, this function may
    take a while to finish.
    '''
    print('Loading word list from file...')
    # inFile: file
    in_file = open('words.txt', 'r')
    # line: string
    line = in_file.readline()
    # word_list: list of strings
    word_list = line.split()
    print('  ', len(word_list), 'words loaded.')
    in_file.close()
    return word_list


load_words()
```

The code above expected to load words from a file called "words.txt" and return a list. It seems the interpreter reads the file but doesn't load words. I don't understand why. I guess the "readline()" method causing problems.I read python documentation but it's blurry to me.

What I want to know is, why I my "line variable is empty? I'm guessing though. Any other, problems please specify.

And oh... forgot to mention, the python file and the word file are in same directory.

[Here is a picture of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWF6v.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try readlines or post your txt file

Comment: You're just reading the first line in your file. Could it be that it's empty?

Comment: Please provide a sample input, and output, as *formatted text*, not images, or links to images. Provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go...sample code...try to code as suggsd

```
def function():
    word = []
    with open file as f:
        for line in f line.append(word)
    Close file
```

Comment: There is a single line only in the file. A string of words separated by space. I tried to load that single string string and split those words and store as a list of words.

Comment: 1. Use subprocess or os.system("sed -i 's/ /\n/g' filename")
2. Then execute this function

Answer (score 0):

```
line = in_file.readline()
```

Reads only one line in the file as a string (First line since this is first call)

```
line = in_file.readlines()
```

Reads all lines in the file as a list of strings

```
line = in_file.read()
```

Reads all the file as a single string.

I think what you want is `in_file.read()`.

Comment: The file contain one line only, but a very long line of string. So, "line = in_file.readline()" should work. Doesn't it?

Comment: I don't know how I can show my file. No file upload facility here eh?